# StackExchange drop-down menu: cannot load sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button

In the drop-down menu at the top left of the screen "all sites" link is not loading. Firebug tells me that the http request returns error 500.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the report.  This should be working now.

Comment: I'm still getting this. The menu doesn't appear, the "StackExchange" logo isn't even clickable.